# Object Format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, format

I want to use object format like this;

```
const ObjX = [{ 1, "category" }, { 2, "category2" }, { 3, "category3" }];
```

Instead of this;

```
const ObjY = [{ id:1, name: "category" }, { id:2, name:"category2" }, { id:3, name:"category3" }];
```

I want to use ObjX but JS is getting compilation error. Is there any solution for this, for example, converting to JSON Object etc...

Comment: Why do you want to use invalid syntax?

Comment: That is invalid syntax. Are you looking for this format `{ 1: "category" }` or `[1, "category" ]`?

Comment: I do not want to use id and name key names @jonrsharpe

Comment: ... *why not?!* And how is JavaScript supposed to know what you think the names of those keys for those values should be? You're basically saying you want to write in a different language.

Comment: yes it is invalid syntax but, none of them. just like this : [{ 1, "category" }]  @adiga

Comment: But I have a data structure like this; [{1,"A"}, {2,"B"}]. I am trying to understand and handle this. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Not in JavaScript you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make this happen using arrays, and a map function

```js
const ObjX = [[1, "category"], [2, "category2"], [3, "category3"]].map(values => ({
  id: values[0],
  name: values[1],
}));
```